# what does "still" imply in a question sentence?

Tags: adverbs

In grammar books it is written that we use "still" in affirmative sentences.

So, what about the following? I am confused.

> Is it still raining?

Comment: It has the same meaning it has in the corresponding affirmative, "It is still raining". "Has it stopped raining yet?" is another way of asking it.

Comment: Same meaning as "Is it continuing to rain?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can actually use *still* in affirmative, negative and questions forms - to indicate that **something is not finished**.

> It's still raining.
>
> Is it still raining?
>
> It still hasn't stopped raining.

It is often used to indicate some element of surprise/concern.
So, your example is correct, but consider that the difference between using *still* and using:

> Has it stopped raining yet?

Is that we often express some surprise/concern when using *still*.

Comment: It might be noteworthy to add that the stress is usually on the word *still* when one is surprised that something is continuing to happen. Ex. "Is it *still* raining?!"

Answer (score 0):

What the grammar books are telling you is that when you're negating a sentence, you can't usually use *still.*

> *It isn't still raining.
>
> It's not raining **anymore**.

In questions, you typically use the affirmative form. But negated questions are possible, in which case, you must use *anymore* instead of *still*:

> Don't you eat cereal for breakfast?
>
> Don't you eat cereal for breakfast anymore?